# What's the meaning of "see through the veneer"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

> a wily interviewer is likely to see through the veneer if you really
>   know nothing about the company.

I guess its meaning is something like "see the inner side(,which is hidden or covered by its appearance or its look)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be answerable by dictionaries, and you should've been able to understand the whole phrase ***see through the veneer*** if you knew the meaning of *see through* and *veneer*.

Because *see through (something)* is a common phrase, I presume that you're not familiar with this sense of ***veneer*** (meaning, a cover or disguise). Here is the meaning of *veneer* in that sentence:.

> **[veneer](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/veneer)**: [in singular] An attractive appearance that covers or disguises someone or something’s true nature or feelings:
>   *'her veneer of composure cracked a little'*

Just to cover the whole phrase, here is a definition of ***see through***:

> **[see through](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/see-through?q=see+through)**: Not be deceived by; detect the true nature of:
>   *'he can see through her lies and deceptions'*

So *a wily interviewer is likely to **see through the veneer*** means that it's likely that he or she will not be deceived or tricked by your cover or your pretending to know. They would see through your cover (read *veneer*). They would see through you. They would know better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are *somewhat* right. The quote in concerned is used as an idiom,

> [to see through the veneer](http://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/persian/course/lower-intermediate/unit-27/session-4/activity-3): *to realise easily that your knowledge is not very detailed*

So, if the interviewer is witty, be careful. You'll be caught for your shallow knowledge.